# Cloud foundry storage

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm developing an application upload and download files on cloud foundry, however I do not know how to access the file storage to recover to download

Comment: Translation courtesy of Google: http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=fr&tl=en&twu=1&u=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426418/cloud-foundry-storage&usg=ALkJrhgp0mvFc4Dy9_2BEEiT0Fm09LP_4Q

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems if you store files on the local file system within CF. Although files can be written by each instance of an app, they will not be visible to other instances of the app. And they will not survive the lifetime of the application instance itself(will be totally gone e.g., when your app is restarted), and hence should be treated as ephemeral.

For now the other options are either storing files as blobs in a CF provisioned service(e.g., MySQL or MongoDB) and then retrieve them from the app. Or since you do have outbound port 80 and 443 access, services that are external to CF.com but are reachable are also an option.

Comment: It's very kind of you offering the translation :)